# Obtaining the first non-null value after a particular key from a firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database that looks something like this:

```
{
    "timetables": [null,{
      //first child
    },{
      //second child
      "8": "null",
      "9": null,
      "10": "sleep"
    } ]
}
```

How do I get the first non-null value after a particular key (say, "8" in the second child) ?

"9" has a null value. So, I should get the value corresponding to "10", "sleep"

How to modify my code in order to do this?

```
let loc = "timetables/" + datetime.getDay(); // datetime.getDay() returns a number from 0-6 which corresponds to one of the children.

var ref = db.ref(loc); // positioning reference at the appropriate child
```

I thought of using the below function, but wasn't able to come up with how to use it exactly:

```
ref.once("value",function(data) {
  app.tell(REPORT_MESSAGE + data.val() + ' at ' + data.key);
});
*/
```

Comment: How do you determine which object the key you’re searching is on? Will your keys always be numerical?

Comment: I first find the current time, and then take my starting key as the hour from that timestamp.

Comment: So, now, starting from this key, I need to find the first object with a non-null value

Comment: But will it always be on the second object in that array, i.e. `.timetables[2]`? And again, will your keys always be numerical?

Comment: Yes. You can assume that its on timetables[2] for this question.

Comment: And yeah, key's always numerical

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

1. the object shown in your first snippet is assigned to some variable `obj`,
2. the keys you’re looking for are always on the object `obj.timetables[2]` (i.e. “`second child`”),
3. those keys will always be numerical, and
4. the “particular key” from which you’re searching is assigned to some variable `fromKey`,

you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with `[]` and `obj.timetables[2]` as arguments in order to transform the object to an array, which will be far easier to work with, then [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to search *from* a certain key, then just [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the first non-null value:

```
const result = Object.assign([], obj).slice(fromKey + 1).find((value) => value !== null);

console.log(result); // "sleep"
```

So, for example:

```js
const obj = {
    "8": "null",
    "9": null,
    "10": "sleep"
  },
  fromKey = 8;

console.log(Object.assign([], obj).slice(fromKey + 1).find((value) => value !== null));
```

Comment: How do I assign a json file's content to a variable obj?

Comment: @AjaySubramanian Isn’t that object just `data.val()` in your `ref.once` callback?